# "Amount of boxes" vs "number of boxes" in non discrete graph

Tags: word-choice, numbers, quantifiers, premodifiers

I have a graph where I show number of boxes that a machine can service per minute. The data may not always give a whole number (for example, a machine may be able to service 2.3 boxes / per minute).

I am wondering how to label the axes on this graph.

I have observed that *number* tends to be used for integer quantities (for instance, *number of people*, or *number of potatoes), whereas *amount* is used for uncountable quantities, that often have fractions (such as *1.5 gallons of paint*).

Which should I use to label my graph, *number of boxes* or *amount of boxes*?

Comment: This is really more of a math question. Perhaps you should try http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clearly on topic. I hope I have not changed the meaning of it too much - if so, please feel free to comment here and/or edit the question further.

Comment: @psmears: Thanks. This makes more sense at EL&U now. I tried to delete my close vote, but I see there is no mechanism to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction made in English is slightly different to the one made in mathematics. Here the distinction is between *countable* and *uncountable* nouns.

For *countable* nouns (such as *person*, *dog*, *pen* and *box*):

- *a*/*an* are used to refer to one (indefinite) item
- *Number* is used to describe how many

For *uncountable* nouns (such as *sugar*, *paint* and so on):

- *some* is used to refer to an (indefinite) quantity
- *amount* (or another word, such as *quantity*) is used to describe how much

Note that this is a property of the nouns, rather than the substances involved - so I would say *some paint*, but *a gallon of paint*, since *gallon* is countable (even though I'm still talking about paint).

In this example, since you are talking about boxes, which are countable, it sounds better to use *number* - even though the number in question might not be a whole number.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you're not giving an integral number of boxes, so you should use *number of boxes per minute,* because the correct term for measuring boxes is *number* and not *amount.*

Answer (score 2):

It sounds something like a question about [continuous versus discrete variables](http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/GeNIeHelp/Decision-theoretic_Modeling/Discrete.htm), but "discrete" does not mean "integer". I am not sure there is a special word for a graph that shows non-integral values...it's not like you are "smoothing" the graph, right?